# Why is the electron magnetic moment always parallel to the spin for an electron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-spin

Consider the Hamiltonian

$$\hat{H}=\frac{1}{2}\omega\vec{B}\cdot \vec{\sigma}$$

where $\vec{\sigma}$ is the Pauli vector $=\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_x & \sigma_y & \sigma_z \end{pmatrix}$, $\omega$ is the frequency of the magnetic field $\vec{B}=\begin{pmatrix}B_x & B_y & B_z \end{pmatrix}$

The electron spin is described by a 2 dimensional hilbert space. Suppose we pick the basis of this space as the spin up and spin down states$\{\lvert 1\rangle,\lvert 0\rangle\}$. Then any spin state can be written as follows, with the probability amplitudes $a,b$ subjected to the usual normalisation constraints
$$\lvert s(t)\rangle=a(t)\lvert 1\rangle+b(t)\lvert 0\rangle$$

The probability of measuring +1 in some direction $\vec{\sigma}\cdot \hat{n}$, t seconds later can be easily determined by first evolving a given $\lvert s(0)\rangle$ with $e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat{H}t}$ to get $\lvert s(t)\rangle$ and then compute $||\langle \lambda_+\lvert s(t)\rangle||^2$ where $\lambda_+$ is the eigenvector correspond to +1 for the measurement in the $\hat{n}$ direction. Therefore, we can easily see that what the transformation did by the magnetic field is effectively rotating the spin state.

The magnetic moment of an electron is related to its spin by

$$\vec{\mu}=\frac{ge}{2m}\frac{\hbar}{2}\vec{\sigma}$$

The above calculations however does not seemed to shed any light on how the magnetic moment is influenced by the Hilbert space of the spin state(?)

> How do we know (experimentally and theoretically) that the spin must always align with the magnetic moment of the electron (assuming the electron is in a system such that its orbital angular momentum contribution is negligible)?

A brief look at Dirac equation only explain why there is spin (because this arise because when we put quantum mechanics and relativity together, which result in a wavefunction with 4 components), but there is no mention on its relationship with the magnetic moment

Comment: What's your definition of a magnetic moment? For me it is a quantity that couples linearly to a magnetic field. Spin does that.

Comment: I am not very sure, given that we cannot treat electron like classical current loops. The only thing I am certain is that a magnetic moment makes the object that possess it to respond to the magnetic field like a bar magnet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Key experiment to test this hypothesis would be the [Einstein-de Haas experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93de_Haas_effect). Assuming the magnetic moment doesn't align with the electron spin, the measurement would yield a Lande-factor $g \neq 2$, in contradiction with the prediction by the Dirac- (or linearized Pauli-)equation.

Comment: Theoretical half of the answer [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32625475#32625475)